# AngularJS ui-grid keep selection state when replacing data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid bound to an object array called `data` like this:

```
$scope.grd = {
        enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        columnDefs: [
                { field: 'id', name: 'ID' },
                { field: 'name', name: 'Name' },
                { field: 'tags', name: 'Tags' }
        ],
        data: "data"
};
```

if I now replace an item in the array like this:

```
$scope.data[i] = replacementData;
```

the grid is updated correctly but the selection state is lost.
I guess the `selection` module simple doesn't support this though the `core` module [does](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/112_swapping_data).

**Is there a way to get the selection state of an item before replacing it?**

I found this [GridRow](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:GridRow) class in the docs of the selection module that has an `isSelected` property but no ideas how to get it...

Here is a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KVRzJQaSyaBxKeRLRokw?p=preview) that demonstrates the behavior - notice that the `selectionCount` is also wrong after the row is replaced, so there must be some kind of selected item info somewhere.

**Update**: It seems that replacing an item in the bound array doesn't remove the [GridRow](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridRow) that ui-grid uses internally (that also is the reason why the selectedCount is wrong). Calling `unSelectRow` before replacing the item fixes the count but the `GridRow`still exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up copying all the properties from the `replacementData` over the old `data` object. That way the selection state is kept, and no new `GridRow` get's created.

[Updated Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KVRzJQaSyaBxKeRLRokw?p=preview)

```
angular.extend($scope.data[i], replacementData);
```